# When implementing redis with node, how do you add multiple json object to Hmset or hset or any data type?

Tags: node.js, redis

As for example->

```
var redis = require('redis');    
var port=6379;    
var host="127.0.0.1";    
var redisClient=null;

redisClient = redis.createClient(port, host);
redisClient.on('connect',function(err,reply){
    if(err)
        {
            console.log("Erro with connectivity");

        }
    else
        {
            console.log("connected with redis");     

        }
  });
```

data variable is a multiple json object

```
 redisClient.hset('users',data);

    redisClient.hgetall('users',function(err,object){
   if(err) 
       {
           console.log("Getting Hmset Error");
       }
    else
        {
            console.log("----Retrieving HMSET--");
            console.log(object);
            console.log("---End Retriving HMSET");
        }
});
```

but json is not added perfect manner .

give result like this.

```
data= { javascript: 'AngularJS',
  css: 'Bootstrap',
  users: '[object Object]',
  node: 'Express',
  '[object Object]': '[object Object]' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Serialize your data befor hset. E.g. 
`redisClient.hset ('users', JSON.stringify (data));`

Answer (score 0):

Redis works with strings, you need to convert your JSON (which is actually a JavaScript object) to a JSON string:

```
redisClient.hset('users', JSON.stringify(data));
```

You will then have to parse that JSON string back into a JavaScript object when you fetch it:

```
redisClient.hget('users', function (err, str) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);

    var data = JSON.parse(str); // note this might throw an exception
});
```

One thing to note is that you're not passing a callback into your hset method which means it's not guaranteed to have completed by the time you call hget. You should look at fixing that too.

Answer (score 0):

Redis working with this datatypes in order to manipulate JSON you have to convert in strings

```
redisClient.hset('users', JSON.stringify(data));

strings — a sequence of binary safe bytes up to 512 MB.
hashes — a collection of key value pairs.
lists — an in-insertion-order collection of strings.
sets — a collection of unique strings with no ordering.
sorted sets — a collection
```